# Tampermonkey: don't allow alert boxes

Tags: javascript, alert, tampermonkey

Is there any script in tampermonkey to automatically close alert boxes as soon as they appear? I already tried `window.close()` but it closes the entire tab. Is there a script to close the alert box?